# Efficient way to replace a fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have created a **MainActivity** like TabActivity (only like) and added four `Fragments` to it. At one time only one can be displayed.  So when any one **tab**(`image`) is clicked I hide all other fragment and show the fragment associated with the tab. I am successful in achieving it. I have found two solution to do the same work but I want to know which one is efficient and which I prefer

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity //implements FragmentDelegate, FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
{
    private final String TAG = "Main";
    public LinearLayout tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4;
    public ImageView img1,img2,img3,img4;

    Fragment[] frag = new Fragment[4];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.practicing);

        init();
    }   

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void showFragment(int x)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag[j]).commit();
            if(j !=x )
            {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frag[j]).commit();
            }
        }
        //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag[x]).commit();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(frag[x]).commit();
    }
    private void init()
    {
        tab1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
        tab2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
        tab3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab3);
        tab4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab4);
        img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tab_img1);
        img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tab_img2);
        img3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tab_img3);
        img4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tab_img4); 

        frag[0] = new Article();
        frag[1] = new Forum();
        frag[2] = new Medias();
        frag[3] = new Profile();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag[i])
            //.addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
        }   
        showFragment(0);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) 
    {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.tab1)) 
        {           
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.articles_on);
            img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.forum_off);
            img3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_off);
            img4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_off);

            showFragment(0);
        } 
        else if(view == findViewById(R.id.tab2)) 
        {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.articles_off);
            img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.forum_on);
            img3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_off);
            img4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_off);

            showFragment(1);
        }
        else if(view == findViewById(R.id.tab3))
        {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.articles_off);
            img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.forum_off);
            img3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_on);
            img4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_off);
        }
        else if(view == findViewById(R.id.tab4))
        {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.articles_off);
            img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.forum_off);
            img3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video_off);
            img4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_on);

            showFragment(3);
        }
    }
}
```

see the `showFragment()` function in MainActivity. it can do the same work by two different ways

1. By hiding all fragment and show the fragment which you want to show.

   ```
       private void showFragment(int x)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
           {
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag[j]).commit();
           }
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag[x]).commit();
       }
   ```
2. Detaching all activity and attach the fragment which you want to show. In this method i have to add `SuppressLint("NewApi")` .
   ..

   ```
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   private void showFragment(int x)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
       {
           if(j != x)
           {
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frag[j]).commit();
           }
       }
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(frag[x]).commit();
   }
   ```

According to my thinking , the second method is efficient but I want to know your opinion about this.

**it is my Supposition / Understanding (may be wrong)**

When we hide all fragment but show our desire one. These fragments hide but take space/memory. while when we attach it will Recreate with the last state save and don't take space before recreating.

The `detach` method removes the fragment from the UI, but its `state` is maintained by the `FragmentManager`. This means you can reuse this `fragment` by calling the `attach` method, with a modified `ViewHierarchy`

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter work on which api level.

Comment: On all of them? Why do you ask? A `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is for a `ViewPager`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller share some resource and tutorials on FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: Here you can find [**the official guides on the subject**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: i have accepted buddy and thanks for your Response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you simply using a `ViewPager`? And both methods are pretty much equal, no significant difference is there. Would you expect there to be one? You are holding a reference to all Fragments in one array. You are not efficiently recycling `Fragments` like a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` would for a `ViewPager` you are just constantly holding the reference to all of them. How you hide and show the Fragments makes no difference all the `Fragments` are sill constantly in memory.

And you don't need to perform a `FragmentTransaction` for every single `Fragment`. If you really want to improve performance, than replace all `Fragments` in one single `FragmentTransaction` like this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
for(int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
    transaction.hide(...);
}
transaction.show(...);
transaction.commit();
```

That you perform 5 `FragmentTransactions` here:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
    if(j !=x)
    {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frag[j]).commit();
    }
}
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(frag[x]).commit();
```

Instead of combining all of that into one is surely a much bigger drag on performance than the difference between `detach()`/`attach()` and `hide()`/`show()`.

But for the record: using `detach()` and `attach()` instead of `hide()` and `show()` would be slightly better memory-wise because those two methods allow for the view hierarchy of unused `Fragments` to be destroyed.